# Generate the vertices of a circle in SDL2 (C++)

Tags: c++, sdl-2

Is there a way to automagically generate the vertices of a circle? I know how to render it and all that I just need a way to input a set amount of vertices and then generate the circle's vertices (the number of them) based on that number.

Comment: Generate a central vertex, then pick the number of vertices to wrap around, generate those at fixed offset degrees using sin and cos, then render as a triangle fan.

Comment: _oh ok thats totally super simple_

Comment: @vandench do you know how to generate those points with sin and cos?

Comment: The `sin` and `cos` of angle θ are `y` and `x` components respectively on the unit circle. The unit circle is in the range of [0, 2π). So choose a number of vertices, use the current index in the equation `i/2nπ` to determine θ, then use `sin` and `cos` to get the `y` and `x` components of the vertex, you can also multiply these by a constant to scale the circle, or add a vector constant to translate the circle. Fill a list with the central vertex for the fan, then all of the edge vertices, and duplicate the first edge vertice at the end so there are no gaps.

Comment: Once the buffer is bound and your pipeline is setup call `glDrayArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, n + 2);`.

Comment: @vandench That's... OpenGL

Comment: @Debaug Last I checked SDL is used to setup a basic windowing and IO system in C, often used in complement with OpenGL. If you're using a different graphics API then translate the draw call over to your respective API, they're all built on the same hardware and offer essentially the same functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can generate the vertices to approximate a circle is as follows:

```
void GenerateCircle(std::vector<SDL_Vertex> &outCircleVertices, size_t vertexCount, int radius, std::vector<int> &outIndices)
{
    // Size our vector so it can hold all the requested vertices plus our center one
    outCircleVertices.resize(vertexCount + 1);

    // Calculate the angle we'll need to rotate by for each iteration (* (PI / 180) to convert it into radians)
    double segRotationAngle = (360.0 / vertexCount) * (3.14159265 / 180);

    // Here I set a center in the middle of the window as an example. The center point of the circle can be anywhere
    int centerX = WINDOW_WIDTH / 2;
    int centerY = WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2;

    // We need an initial vertex in the center as a point for all of the triangles we'll generate
    outCircleVertices[0].position.x = centerX;
    outCircleVertices[0].position.y = centerY;

    // Set the colour of the center point
    outCircleVertices[0].color.r = 255;
    outCircleVertices[0].color.g = 255;
    outCircleVertices[0].color.b = 255;
    outCircleVertices[0].color.a = 255;

    // Set the starting point for the initial generated vertex. We'll be rotating this point around the origin in the loop
    double startX = 0.0 - radius;
    double startY = 0.0;

    for (int i = 1; i < vertexCount + 1; i++)
    {
        // Calculate the angle to rotate the starting point around the origin
        double finalSegRotationAngle = (i * segRotationAngle);

        // Rotate the start point around the origin (0, 0) by the finalSegRotationAngle (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics) section on two dimensional rotation)
        outCircleVertices[i].position.x = cos(finalSegRotationAngle) * startX - sin(finalSegRotationAngle) * startY;
        outCircleVertices[i].position.y = cos(finalSegRotationAngle) * startY + sin(finalSegRotationAngle) * startX;

        // Set the point relative to our defined center (in this case the center of the screen)
        outCircleVertices[i].position.x += centerX;
        outCircleVertices[i].position.y += centerY;

        // Set the colour for the vertex
        outCircleVertices[i].color.r = 255;
        outCircleVertices[i].color.g = 255;
        outCircleVertices[i].color.b = 255;
        outCircleVertices[i].color.a = 255;

        // Add centre point index
        outIndices.push_back(0);

        // Add generated point index
        outIndices.push_back(i);

        // Add next point index (with logic to wrap around when we reach the start)
        int index = (i + 1) % vertexCount;
        if (index == 0)
        {
            index = vertexCount;
        }
        outIndices.push_back(index);
    }
}
```

Each stage is commented up with an explanation to help with understanding. In my example here I have opted not to duplicate any vertices and instead use indices to describe to the drawing function how it should use each of the vertices to generate triangles. This is a common practice in graphics programming - you'd see this in OpenGL for example.

To use this function simply add

```
std::vector<SDL_Vertex> circleVertices;
std::vector<int> indices;

GenerateCircle(circleVertices, 20, 60, indices);
```

in your initialisation and then add

```
int rc = SDL_RenderGeometry(renderer, NULL, circleVertices.data(), circleVertices.size(), indices.data(), indices.size());
if (rc < 0)
{
    std::cout << SDL_GetError();
}
```

in your rendering loop between the SDL_RenderClear and SDL_RenderPresent calls. Note that you can change the vertexCount that you pass in to generate a circle with more or less triangles for a better or worse approximation. Please also note that if you use the function as is you'll be drawing a white circle, just in case you have a white background and wonder where it is!